# How can I kick a user by ID in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I was wondering how I could make a command that kicks a specific user every time, without having to mention the user.

I am looking for something like this:

```
@client.command()
async def kick(ctx):
  user = #user id
  await user.kick(reason=None)
```

And not like this:

```
@client.command()
async def kick(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
  await member.kick(reason=reason)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can get a member from his/her id by using `discord.Guild.get_member`.

```py
@client.command()
async def kick(ctx):
  user = ctx.guild.get_member(<user id>)
  await user.kick(reason=None)
```

Or you can use `discord.utils.get`. I'd recommend you to use the first one but this is also a option.

```py
@client.command()
async def kick(ctx):
  user = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.members, id=<user id>)
  await user.kick(reason=None)
```

## References

- [`discord.Guild.get_member()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_member)
- [`discord.utils.get()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get)

Comment: Both of these return the error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'kick'`

Comment: Have you enabled intents?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the built in converter for member : discord.Member
like this:

```
from discord.ext import commands

@client.command()
async def kick(ctx, member: commands.MemberConverter, *, reason):
    await ctx.guild.kick(member, reason=reason)
```

correct me if i'm wrong but it should work

you can watch this video if you're confused: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MX29zp9RKlA (this is where i learned all of my discord.py coding stuff)